# Get the value of END AS column in case when in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where i used case when to KNOWN_AS column stating when its null then 'null' else 'not null' end as known_as2. Now in where clause i want to bring rows which only contain 'Not null' .

```
SELECT i.individual_ref, 0, 'KNOWNAS', i.FORENAMES, i.KNOWN_AS,
       case when KNOWN_AS is null then 'Null'  else ' Not null' end as known_as
FROM TestDatabase.dbo.INDIVIDUAL I
JOIN TestDatabase.dbo.MEMBER M ON M.INDIVIDUAL_REF=I.INDIVIDUAL_REF
WHERE  m.member_status IN(33,1316) 
  AND i.KNOWN_AS IS null or i.KNOWN_AS=''
  and m.MEMBER_STATUS in (33,1316)
  and LEN(i.FORENAMES) > '1' and i.FORENAMES !=''
  AND i.FORENAMES IS NOT NULL
```

Reason i'm want help is :-

I have a table which contain Forename, surname and known_as field. 
I want to get members who's known_as field is blank/null and forename is not null or blank and forename length is >1 . How can i achieve it. the member status is from another table call member where i want member who are in active and pending status hence i said WHERE m.member_status IN (33,1316). Any solution please.

Finally I have solved it using

```
 SELECT i.individual_ref,0,'KNOWNAS',
case when KNOWN_AS is null then 'Null'  else ' Not null' end as knownas2
FROM TestDatabase.dbo.INDIVIDUAL I
JOIN TestDatabase.dbo.MEMBER M ON M.INDIVIDUAL_REF=I.INDIVIDUAL_REF
       WHERE  m.member_status IN(33,1316) 
       and len(i.forenames)>2 and
          (IsNull(i.forenames, '') <> '') and (i.known_as is null or i.known_as='')
```

I had to take len(i.forenames, '')>2 instead of 1 because some members also has forename by mistakenly updated as Mr.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think he wants the known_as he made with the case, not the original field

Comment: Derived table is the solution!

Comment: [Logical processing order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement): "... This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps.... 4. WHERE ... 8. SELECT". Unfortunately, the definers of SQL took a massive misstep by having you write clauses in a different order to that in which they're logically processed. Far too late to fix it :-(

Comment: @GordonLinoff Reason i'm want help is :- 

I have a table which contain Forename, surname and known_as field. 
I want to get members who's known_as field is blank/null and forename is not null or blank and forename length is >1 . How can i achieve it. the member status is from another table call member where i want member who are in active and pending status hence i said WHERE m.member_status IN (33,1316). Any solution please.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Reason i'm want help is :- 

I have a table which contain Forename, surname and known_as field. 
I want to get members who's known_as field is blank/null and forename is not null or blank and forename length is >1 . How can i achieve it. the member status is from another table call member where i want member who are in active and pending status hence i said WHERE m.member_status IN (33,1316). Any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

> Now in where clause i want to bring rows which only contain 'Not null' .

Just modify your `WHERE` clause with `IS NOT NULL` as :

```
SELECT i.individual_ref, 0, 'KNOWNAS', i.FORENAMES, i.KNOWN_AS
FROM DiTestDatabase.dbo.INDIVIDUAL I JOIN 
     DiTestDatabase.dbo.MEMBER M 
     ON M.INDIVIDUAL_REF = I.INDIVIDUAL_REF
WHERE m.member_status IN (33,1316) AND
      LEN(i.FORENAMES) > 1 AND i.FORENAMES != '' AND 
      i.FORENAMES IS NOT NULL AND i.KNOWN_AS IS NOT NULL;
```

Note :

- `LEN()` will return `INT` type. So, you don't need to use `''`.

Comment: With your query i'm getting My "Known_as" is not null and blank. I want my known_as column as null or blank.

Comment: Reason i'm want help is :- 

I have a table which contain Forename, surname and known_as field. 
I want to get members who's known_as field is blank/null and forename is not null or blank and forename length is >1 . How can i achieve it. the member status is from another table call member where i want member who are in active and pending status hence i said WHERE m.member_status IN (33,1316). Any solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Might be below query will help you.

```
SELECT i.individual_ref, 0, 'KNOWNAS', i.FORENAMES, i.KNOWN_AS
,CASE WHEN i.KNOWN_AS IS NULL THEN 'null'
      ELSE 'Not null' END AS KNOWN_AS2
FROM DiTestDatabase.dbo.INDIVIDUAL I JOIN 
     DiTestDatabase.dbo.MEMBER M 
     ON M.INDIVIDUAL_REF = I.INDIVIDUAL_REF
WHERE m.member_status IN (33,1316) AND
      LEN(i.FORENAMES) > 1 AND i.FORENAMES != '' AND 
      i.FORENAMES IS NOT NULL AND i.KNOWN_AS IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: With your query i'm getting My "Known_as" is not null and blank. I want my known_as column as null or blank.

Comment: Just change the where condition like ISNULL(i.KNOWN_AS,'')=''. Then u will be get KNOWN_AS value become null or blank. Might be this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

this way we can get solution

`SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT i.individual_ref, 0, 'KNOWNAS', i.FORENAMES, i.KNOWN_AS,
      case when KNOWN_AS is null then 'Null'  else 'Not null' end as known_as
     FROM DiTestDatabase.dbo.INDIVIDUAL I
     JOIN DiTestDatabase.dbo.MEMBER M ON M.INDIVIDUAL_REF=I.INDIVIDUAL_REF
     WHERE  m.member_status IN(33,1316) 
     AND i.KNOWN_AS IS null or i.KNOWN_AS=''
     and m.MEMBER_STATUS in (33,1316)
     and LEN(i.FORENAMES) > 1 and i.FORENAMES !=''
     AND i.FORENAMES IS NOT NULL) t
WHERE t.known_as='Not null'`

Comment: i'm getting an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

Comment: just check you query is running i'm just add a parent query like select * from( your query) where columnname='not null'

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 48
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'tab1'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 48
No column name was specified for column 3 of 'tab1'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
The column 'known_as' was specified multiple times for 'tab1'. im getting this error

Comment: i have removed those columns for which i got the error and now its giving me no value.

Comment: this error was because of column name not mention and two same column name so that i modified column name. you can modified according to you. Let check the updated query

Comment: getting error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.